# XSLT - transform two different XML files into one without duplication of elements

Tags: php, xml, xslt, transform

I have two different XML files: movies.xml and Amazon Product Advertising API XML

This is my XSLT file that transforms both XML files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:aws="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01"
exclude-result-prefixes="aws">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="html">
        <xsl:element name="head">
            <xsl:element name="h2">Movies list</xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="body">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/movies/movie"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="aws:ItemLookupResponse/aws:Items/aws:Item/aws:ItemAttributes/aws:Title"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="movie">
    <xsl:element name="a">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">movie_details.php?movieID=<xsl:value-of select="@movieID"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="br" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="aws:Title">
    <xsl:element name="h2">Amazon Movie 1</xsl:element>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*apply-templates select="/movies/movie* - Loads a list of 5 movie titles from movies.xml and displays them as hyperlinks.

*apply-templates select="aws:ItemLookupResponse/aws:Items/aws:Item/aws:ItemAttributes/aws:Title"* - Loads the movie title from Amazon API xml file and displays it as plain text.

This is my HTML output:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <h2>Movies list</h2>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="movie_details.php?movieID=1">The Dark Knight Rises</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="movie_details.php?movieID=2">Lawless</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="movie_details.php?movieID=3">Inception</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="movie_details.php?movieID=4">Looper</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="movie_details.php?movieID=5">Django Unchained</a>
    <br/>
  </body>
</html>
<html>
  <head>
    <h2>Movies list</h2>
  </head>
  <body><h2>Amazon Movie 1</h2>Dark Knight Rises [Blu-ray] [2012] [US Import]</body>
</html>
```

As you can see these two templates are displayed in separate HTML tags which leads to the Head element "Movies list" being displayed twice for both templates.

If I could somehow put both of these templates into  a single HTML element, so nothing would be duplicated. I've tried to do it several ways but have not succeeded yet.

This is my PHP file that creates two XML files and one XSLT stylesheet. It also generates a signed URL to the amazon product.

```
include('aws_signed_request.php');

$public_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$private_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$associate_tag = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

// generate signed URL
$request = aws_signed_request('co.uk', array(
        'Operation' => 'ItemLookup',
        'ItemId' => 'B004LWZWGK',
        'ResponseGroup' => 'Small'), $public_key, $private_key, $associate_tag);

// do request (you could also use curl etc.)
$response = @file_get_contents($request);
if ($response === FALSE) {
    echo "Request failed.\n";
} else {

    // parse XML
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->load('movies.xml');

    $xml2 = new DOMDocument();
    $xml2->loadXML($response);

    $xsl = new DOMDocument;
    $xsl->load('movies_list.xsl');

    $proc = new XSLTProcessor();
    $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

    echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
    echo $proc->transformToXML($xml2);

}
```

*movies.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="index.xsl"?>
<movies
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="movies.xsd">

<movie movieID="1">
    <title>The Dark Knight Rises</title>
</movie>

<movie movieID="2">
    <title>Lawless</title>
</movie>

<movie movieID="3">
    <title>Inception</title>
</movie>

<movie movieID="4">
    <title>Looper</title>
</movie>

<movie movieID="5">
    <title>Django Unchained</title>
</movie>
</movies>
```

*Amazon product advertising API XML*

```
<ItemLookupResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
   <OperationRequest>
       <HTTPHeaders>
          <Header Name="UserAgent" Value="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22"/>
       </HTTPHeaders>
       <RequestId>a1138e89-4335-4650-80f2-641e3c58b623</RequestId>
       <Arguments>
    <Argument Name="Operation" Value="ItemLookup"/>
    <Argument Name="Service" Value="AWSECommerceService"/>
    <Argument Name="Signature" Value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <Argument Name="AssociateTag" Value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <Argument Name="Version" Value="2011-08-01"/>
    <Argument Name="ItemId" Value="B004LWZWGK"/>
    <Argument Name="AWSAccessKeyId" Value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <Argument Name="Timestamp" Value="2013-03-21T13:56:55.000Z"/>
    <Argument Name="ResponseGroup" Value="Small"/>
       </Arguments>
       <RequestProcessingTime>0.0189320000000000</RequestProcessingTime>
       </OperationRequest>
    <Items>
      <Item>
         <ItemAttributes>
           <Title>
            The Dark Knight Rises (Blu-ray/DVD Combo+UltraViolet Digital Copy)
           </Title>
         </ItemAttributes>
      </Item>
    </Items>
</ItemLookupResponse>
```

Browser Output:

[image: browser].

Comment: Alex, show some snippets of both XML-files...

Comment: I've updated my post with XML files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I cannot repro the problem**.

**With your XSLT code** (slightly changed to access "movies.xml" by calling the `document()` function):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:aws="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01"
exclude-result-prefixes="aws">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="vMoviesDoc" select=
 "document('file:///c:/temp/delete/movies.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="html">
        <xsl:element name="head">
            <xsl:element name="h2">Movies list</xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="body">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$vMoviesDoc/movies/movie"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="aws:ItemLookupResponse/aws:Items/aws:Item/aws:ItemAttributes/aws:Title"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="movie">
    <xsl:element name="a">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">movie_details.php?movieID=<xsl:value-of select="@movieID"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="br" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="aws:Title">
    <xsl:element name="h2">Amazon Movie 1</xsl:element>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided *Amazon product advertising API XML* document:**

```
<ItemLookupResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
   <OperationRequest>
       <HTTPHeaders>
          <Header Name="UserAgent" Value="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22"/>
       </HTTPHeaders>
       <RequestId>a1138e89-4335-4650-80f2-641e3c58b623</RequestId>
       <Arguments>
    <Argument Name="Operation" Value="ItemLookup"/>
    <Argument Name="Service" Value="AWSECommerceService"/>
    <Argument Name="Signature" Value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <Argument Name="AssociateTag" Value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <Argument Name="Version" Value="2011-08-01"/>
    <Argument Name="ItemId" Value="B004LWZWGK"/>
    <Argument Name="AWSAccessKeyId" Value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <Argument Name="Timestamp" Value="2013-03-21T13:56:55.000Z"/>
    <Argument Name="ResponseGroup" Value="Small"/>
       </Arguments>
       <RequestProcessingTime>0.0189320000000000</RequestProcessingTime>
       </OperationRequest>
    <Items>
      <Item>
         <ItemAttributes>
           <Title>
            The Dark Knight Rises (Blu-ray/DVD Combo+UltraViolet Digital Copy)
           </Title>
         </ItemAttributes>
      </Item>
    </Items>
</ItemLookupResponse>
```

and having the provided XML document (file "movies.xml") in the local directory "C:\temp\delete":

```
<movies xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="movies.xsd">
    <movie movieID="1">
        <title>The Dark Knight Rises</title>
    </movie>
    <movie movieID="2">
        <title>Lawless</title>
    </movie>
    <movie movieID="3">
        <title>Inception</title>
    </movie>
    <movie movieID="4">
        <title>Looper</title>
    </movie>
    <movie movieID="5">
        <title>Django Unchained</title>
    </movie>
</movies>
```

**the transformation produces the following result, where there is no duplication of `head`:**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <h2>Movies list</h2>
   </head>
   <body>
      <a href="movie_details.php?movieID=1">The Dark Knight Rises</a>
      <br/>
      <a href="movie_details.php?movieID=2">Lawless</a>
      <br/>
      <a href="movie_details.php?movieID=3">Inception</a>
      <br/>
      <a href="movie_details.php?movieID=4">Looper</a>
      <br/>
      <a href="movie_details.php?movieID=5">Django Unchained</a>
      <br/>
      <h2>Amazon Movie 1</h2>
            The Dark Knight Rises (Blu-ray/DVD Combo+UltraViolet Digital Copy)
           </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Dimitre. I have double checked everything and I'm still getting the duplicate of html elements containing the head element in each one. I think my PHP code is causing the problem as I'm creating and echoing two separate xml files. They are probably overlaying each other and causing all the html tags to duplicate. I have updated my post with an image of what my browser is displaying.

Comment: @Alex, I have run the transformation from this answer with all the 11 different XSLT processors I am working with -- all of them produce the same correct result. If you are using a compliant XSLT processor, then the only reason could be that at least one of the XML documents or the transformation itself, is different from the ones used in this answer.

Comment: @Alex, after adding the access to "movies.xml" with `document()`, did you remove the `echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);` from your PHP? You're running 2 separate transforms. You only need to run the transform on the "$response" XML.

Comment: I have fixed the problem by loading movies.xml as a document in XSLT and removing the "$xml = new DOMDocument();" "$xml->load('movies.xml');" and "echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);" lines from my PHP code. Now everything is displayed in one html element with no duplication of any tags. Thank you Dimitre and Daniel for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the XSLTProcessor doesn't allow you to set XML content as a parameter (the setParameter function accepts only a string), so you'll need to use the XSLT `document` function to process multiple input documents, as discussed [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/03/06/xslt.html) and [here](http://p2p.wrox.com/xslt/79311-how-process-multiple-input-xml-files-single-xslt.html).  You would need to save your response from Amazon as a file in the file system, then your XSLT could look something like this (in which I have simplified your file names):

```
<xsl:variable name="amazon" select="document('amazon.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Movies List</h2>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="movies/movie" />
            <h2>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($amazon/aws:ItemLookupResponse/aws:Items/aws:Item/aws:ItemAttributes/aws:Title)"/>
            </h2>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="movie">
    <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">movie_details.php?movieID=<xsl:value-of select="@movieID"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </a>
    <br/>
</xsl:template>
```

EDIT:  Code modified as per your comments to my original answer, and language about "many-to-one" problem removed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Jollymorphic. I have applied your solution but unfortunately I'm still getting duplicated "Movies list" h2 tag. Maybe I haven't explained my question properly, but all I want is to display the "Movies list" header text, then a list of 5 hyperlinked movie titles and then "The Dark knight amazon movie title" below. I don't want to have any relation between the 5 movie titles and the amazon title, I'm just trying to include amazon api in my movies list page and see how it's going to work. All I want is to display it in one HTML tag with no "Movies list" title duplicated.